# Python extract sentence containing word

Tags: python, regex, text-segmentation

I am trying to extract all the sentence containing a specified word from a text.

```
txt="I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
txt = "." + txt
re.findall(r"\."+".+"+"apple"+".+"+"\.", txt)
```

but it is returning me :

```
[".I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."]
```

instead of :

```
[".I like to eat apple., "Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
In [3]: re.findall(r"([^.]*?apple[^.]*\.)",txt)                                                                                                                             
Out[4]: ['I like to eat apple.', " Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Comment: how can I get only `apple` by adding boundaries out:[ 'I like to eat apple.']

Answer (score 32):

No need for regex:

```
>>> txt = "I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
>>> [sentence + '.' for sentence in txt.split('.') if 'apple' in sentence]
['I like to eat apple.', " Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Comment: @user2187202 You can accept my answer if you want or accept the regex solution if that was actually what you needed since you did tag it as a regex question, I'm not sure if that was essential or not though

Answer (score 9):

```
In [7]: import re

In [8]: txt=".I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."

In [9]: re.findall(r'([^.]*apple[^.]*)', txt)
Out[9]: ['I like to eat apple', " Let's go buy some apples"]
```

But note that @jamylak's `split`-based solution is faster:

```
In [10]: %timeit re.findall(r'([^.]*apple[^.]*)', txt)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 us per loop

In [11]: %timeit [s+ '.' for s in txt.split('.') if 'apple' in s]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 819 ns per loop
```

The speed difference is less, but still significant, for larger strings:

```
In [24]: txt = txt*10000

In [25]: %timeit re.findall(r'([^.]*apple[^.]*)', txt)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.49 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit [s+'.' for s in txt.split('.') if 'apple' in s]
100 loops, best of 3: 6.35 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi @unutbu -- What if I have a list `['apple', 'orange']`, how should we approach it then?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [str.split](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split),

```
>>> txt="I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
>>> txt.split('. ')
['I like to eat apple', 'Me too', "Let's go buy some apples."]

>>> [ t for t in txt.split('. ') if 'apple' in t]
['I like to eat apple', "Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r"\."+".+"+"apple"+".+"+"\."
```

This line is a bit odd; why concatenate so many separate strings? You could just use r'..+apple.+.'.

Anyway, the problem with your regular expression is its greedy-ness. By default a `x+` will match `x` as often as it possibly can. So your `.+` will match as many characters (*any* characters) as possible; including dots and `apple`s.

What you want to use instead is a non-greedy expression; you can usually do this by adding a `?` at the end: `.+?`.

This will make you get the following result:

```
['.I like to eat apple. Me too.']
```

As you can see you no longer get both the apple-sentences but still the `Me too.`. That is because you still match the `.` after the `apple`, making it impossible to not capture the following sentence as well.

A working regular expression would be this: `r'\.[^.]*?apple[^.]*?\.'`

Here you don’t look at *any* characters, but only those characters which are not dots themselves. We also allow not to match any characters at all (because after the `apple` in the first sentence there are no non-dot characters). Using that expression results in this:

```
['.I like to eat apple.', ". Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the sample in question is `extract sentence containing substring` instead of
`extract sentence containing word`. How to solve the `extract sentence containing word` problem through python is as follows:

A word can be in the begining|middle|end of the sentence. Not limited to the example in the question, I would provide a general function of searching a word in a sentence:

```
def searchWordinSentence(word,sentence):
    pattern = re.compile(' '+word+' |^'+word+' | '+word+' $')
    if re.search(pattern,sentence):
        return True
```

limited to the example in the question, we can solve like:

```
txt="I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
word = "apple"
print [ t for t in txt.split('. ') if searchWordofSentence(word,t)]
```

The corresponding output is:

```
['I like to eat apple']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
search = "test"
text = "This is a test text! Best text ever. Cool"
contains = [s for s in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) if search in s]
```