# Python extracting sentence containing 2 words

Tags: python, regex, nltk, sentence, text-segmentation

I have the same problem that was discussed in this link [Python extract sentence containing word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032832/python-extract-sentence-containing-word), but the difference is that I want to find 2 words in the same sentence. I need to extract sentences from a corpus, which contains 2 specific words. Does anyone could help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you mean:

```
import re
txt="I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
define_words = 'some apple'
print re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s[^.]*\.)" % define_words,txt)  

Output: [" Let's go buy some apples."]
```

You can also try with:

```
define_words = raw_input("Enter string: ")
```

Check if the sentence contain the defined words:

```
import re
txt="I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
words = 'go apples'.split(' ')

sentences = re.findall(r"([^.]*\.)" ,txt)  
for sentence in sentences:
    if all(word in sentence for word in words):
        print sentence
```

Comment: Thanks badc0re, but I forgot to mention that those 2 words don't need to be consecutive. Is it a way to use regex and get the same result as in the answer below by moliware?

Comment: I have added another solution similar to @moliware with using regex.

Answer (score 2):

This would be simple using the [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package together with Python's builtin [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Basically, iterate through the sentences of your text, and check if their exists an intersection between the set of words in the sentence and your search words.

```
from text.blob import TextBlob

search_words = set(["buy", "apples"])
blob = TextBlob("I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples.")
matches = []
for sentence in blob.sentences:
    words = set(sentence.words)
    if search_words & words:  # intersection
        matches.append(str(sentence))
print(matches)
# ["Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Update:
Or, more Pythonically,

```
from text.blob import TextBlob

search_words = set(["buy", "apples"])
blob = TextBlob("I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples.")
matches = [str(s) for s in blob.sentences if search_words & set(s.words)]
print(matches)
# ["Let's go buy some apples."]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an answer using nltk. And I guess that those 2 words don't need to be consecutive right?

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> text = 'I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples.'
>>> words = ['like', 'apple']
>>> sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
>>> for sentence in sentences:
...   if (all(map(lambda word: word in sentence, words))):
...      print sentence
...
I like to eat apple.
```