# Python extracting sentence containing 2 words with conditions of window size

Tags: python, regex, string, list, find

I have the same problem that was discussed in this link
[Python extracting sentence containing 2 words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529140/python-extracting-sentence-containing-2-words)

but the difference is that i need to extract only sentences that containe the two words in a defined size windows search . for exemple:

```
sentences = [ 'There was peace and happiness','hello every one',' How to Find Inner Peace ,love and Happiness ','Inner peace is closely related to happiness']

search_words= ['peace','happiness']
windows_size = 3  #search only the three words after the 1est word 'peace'
#output must be :
output= ['There was peace and happiness',' How to Find Inner Peace love and Happiness ']
```

Comment: Explain a little bit clearly. Your output does not match the condition.

Comment: i don't see where the output doesn't match the condiction , for the 1st sentence in the output : 'happiness is in the 2nd position of the windows so it's satisfay the condiction , and in the 2nd sentence of the output : 'happiness is in the 3rd position and it satisfay the condiction so it's true . where for the last sentence in the input sentences : the word 'happiness' is in the 5th position so we don't take it . the window count start from the position i+1 . i hope it's more clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a crude solution.

```py
def search(sentences, keyword1, keyword2, window=3):
    res = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        words = sentence.lower().split(" ")
        if keyword1 in words and keyword2 in words:
            keyword1_idx = words.index(keyword1)
            keyword2_idx = words.index(keyword2)
            if keyword2_idx - keyword1_idx <= window:
                res.append(sentence)
    return res
```

Given a `sentences` list and two keywords, `keyword1` and `keyword2`, we iterate through the `sentences` list one by one. We split the sentence into words, assuming that the words are separated by a single space. Then, after performing a cursory check of whether or not both keywords are present in the `words` list, we find the index of each keyword in `words` to make sure that the indices are at most `window` apart, *i.e.* the words are close together within `window` words. We append only the sentences that satisfy this condition to the `res` list, and return that result.

Comment: thank you so much , that was very helpfull very simple.

Comment: Glad it helped!