# Python extracting sentence containing word excluding the numeric strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a similar problem that was discussed in this link [Python extract sentence containing word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032832/python-extract-sentence-containing-word), but i do not want a numeric string to end the sentence.

eg:

```
The apt subtitle for the binoculars will be 9015.18.1190, CTS, which provides for binoculars. The rate of duty on this will be free.
```

When I tried this:

```
import re
txt="The apt subtitle for the binoculars will be 9015.18.1190, CTS, which provides for binoculars. The rate of duty on this will be free."
define_words = 'apt subtitle'
print (re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s[^.]*\.)" % define_words,txt))
```

Actual output:

```
The apt subtitle for the binoculars will be 9015.
```

However the expected output is:

```
The apt subtitle for the binoculars will be 9015.18.1190, CTS, which provides for binoculars.
```

Can someone help me on achieving the expected output?

Comment: If there is just one sentence (`txt`) you need to handle, you can simply use `txt.split('The rate of duty on this will be free.')[0]`. However this will not provide you systematic solution in case there are many sentences to handle

Comment: You can do a split on the sentences and then find whether the desired word exists in the sentence and then just print that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [lookahead regex](http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html) to assert matching ending with a `.` thats not follow by numeric

This works for your example input, however might need to tweak a bit to be more generic to handle more cases.

```
import re
txt="The apt subtitle for the binoculars will be 9015.18.1190, CTS, which provides for binoculars. The rate of duty on this will be free."
define_words = 'apt subtitle'
print (re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s.*?\.)(?!\d)" % define_words,txt))
# The apt subtitle for the binoculars will be 9015.18.1190, CTS, which provides for binoculars.
```

Comment: Hey you are right.. I just learnt that the problem is not because of the numbers.. There are braces and double quotes in the sentence.. Im able to remove braces using `txt=str(txt).strip('()')` but im not able to remove the double quotes. However these double quotes are not present in all the sentences. How can i handle them?

Comment: where is the double quote, can you show example and expected output ? you can use `txt = txt.strip('()"')` to strip off round bracket and double quote

Comment: Hi @Skycc, liked the solution. I have a similar kinda problem. Would you please check `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71430999/extract-a-sentence-based-on-specific-phrase`